# VSTS Bombing out NPM Install?

Tags: angular, npm, azure-devops, angular-cli

I have a VSTS Batch Script like so:

```
cd (my UI dir)
echo npm install...
npm install
echo ng build --output-path %1\ui
ng build --output-path %1\ui
echo npm run ng build --output-path %1\ui
npm run ng build --output-path %1\ui
echo All done.
```

yet, inexplicably, I cannot seem to get past the npm install line.  My output resembles this:

```
2018-07-28T20:03:12.8414522Z ##[section]Starting: Run script BuildUi.bat
2018-07-28T20:03:12.8705378Z ==============================================================================
2018-07-28T20:03:12.8705624Z Task         : Batch Script
2018-07-28T20:03:12.8705839Z Description  : Run a windows cmd or bat script and optionally allow it to change the environment
2018-07-28T20:03:12.8706039Z Version      : 1.1.3
2018-07-28T20:03:12.8706207Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-07-28T20:03:12.8706405Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613733)
2018-07-28T20:03:12.8706654Z ==============================================================================
2018-07-28T20:03:12.8810206Z ##[command]D:\Projects\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\1\s\BuildUi.bat D:\Projects\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\1\a
2018-07-28T20:03:12.9157783Z 
2018-07-28T20:03:12.9158312Z D:\Projects\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\1\s>cd myuiproject 
2018-07-28T20:03:12.9158475Z 
2018-07-28T20:03:12.9158666Z D:\Projects\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\1\s\myuiproject>echo npm install... 
2018-07-28T20:03:12.9158918Z npm install...
2018-07-28T20:03:12.9159011Z 
2018-07-28T20:03:12.9159198Z D:\Projects\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\1\s\myuiproject>npm install 
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6909464Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6911145Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6912865Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6913360Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6914230Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6914844Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6915700Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6916232Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6917088Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules\karma\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6917734Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6919280Z npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/core@~5.1.0 but none was installed.
2018-07-28T20:03:38.6919744Z npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/common@~5.1.0 but none was installed.
2018-07-28T20:03:38.7159772Z ##[section]Finishing: Run script BuildUi.bat
```

There's some warnings here which I'm comfortable ignoring, but the batch file is considered "successfully executed" and continues on... sans my built UI project (which is kinda an important piece!)

Can someone explain to me what is going on here, and how I can build my UI project from a VSTS CI task?  I don't know if this is a problem with VSTS, NPM, or angular CLI, but this stupid simple thing is completely blocking me from setting up my CI build.

**SOLUTION**

As @CeceDong suggested, I was using the wrong task to make this happen.

- First, I needed to ensure I had the proper version of Node.js installed (for Angular 6 CLI, that's v8.9+).  Conveniently, there is a task to ensure that the proper version of Node is installed.
- Second, I needed to invoke the `npm` commmand in the angular project directory to run `npm install`.
- Finally, I needed to run a Command Line task: `npm run ng build` in my angular project directory.  It wouldn't accept a regular `ng build` command.  Once I got these steps worked out, it operated as I expected it to.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your build definition? Which build agent do you use? Is your script working locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [npm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=vsts) task to run `npm install` or `npm custom` to see whether you can have a successful build:

[image]

Comment: This is part of what I did.  I'll expound in my question.